# Play custom audio files on Ionic Cordova Local Notifications IOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Is a a workaround to play custom audio files or device ringing tones on ionic Cordova local notifications IOS. I want to play audios recorded on my app on Local notifications trigger

Your Environment
Device OS is IOS 16.1.2 Ionic:

Ionic CLI : 5.4.5 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic) Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 5.9.4 @angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.1.4

Cordova:

Cordova CLI : 11.0.0 Cordova Platforms : ios 6.2.0 Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 14 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.15.4 native-run : 1.6.0 (update available: 1.7.1)

System:

ios-deploy : 1.10.0 ios-sim

Comment: You cant play custom audio as noti sound.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive it like this:

```
export class HomePage {
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public platform: Platform
  ) {
    this.platform.ready()
      .then(() => {
        console.log(this.platform.is('android'))
        LocalNotifications.schedule({
          id: 1,
          text: 'Single LocalNotification',
          sound: this.setSound(),
          data: { secret: 'hellloo' }
        });
      })
  }
  setSound() {
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      return 'file://assets/sounds/shame.mp3'
    } else {
      return 'file://assets/sounds/bell.mp3'
    }
  }
}
```

The old answer from [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/local-notifications-sound/78877).

Comment: Hi Louay thanks for the response, l have already done that to load an audio in the assets and reference it the way you say it works.
I want to play audios that you are located in the Documents folder using the File plugin
 const path = this.file.documentsDirectory + 'myAudios';
I want to play files in documentsDirectory/myAudios/test.m4a

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the documentation about playing audio outside the package, I think you can't archive it without adding the audio inside the assets folder at least.